# Invalid object name error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

I have two selects:

```
  select * from thr_prsnjob 
  select * from tHR_PrsnJob
```

First one is working ok. Second returns error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.tHR_PrsnJob'.
```

Database collation is: Collation=SQL_Croatian_CP1250_CI_AS

I should get this error if database was case sensitive. If CI it should work. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you have those selects? Are both one after another?

Comment: Try using Fully Qualified Names. `Select * from DB_Name.Schema_name.tHR_PrsnJob`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes.   Also this works: select * from tHR_Prsnjob

Comment: @NoDisplayName This also doesn't work: Select * from Roto_55.dbo.tHR_PrsnJob

Comment: Actually first 4 selects are working, and last two not:
select * from tHR_Prsnjob        
select * from thr_prsnjob
select * from thr_Prsnjob
Select * from Roto_55.dbo.tHR_Prsnjob 

select * from tHR_PrsnJob
Select * from Roto_55.dbo.tHR_PrsnJob

Comment: Possibly something to do with Croatian handling of `nj` as a single letter?

Comment: @DavidG I thinkyou're on something, look this: `if (cast('nj' as sysname)=cast('nJ' as sysname)) 
select 1
else 
select 0
/*returns 0*/    

if (cast('aj' as sysname)=cast('aJ' as sysname)) 
select 1
else 
select 0
/*returns 1 */`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Croatian language the letters `nj` together are effectively treated as a single letter as is `lj`. This is known as a [digraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_%28orthography%29#Digraphs_versus_letters).

It appears that SQL Server is also treating these letters in the same way. Consider the following 4 statements:

```
CREATE TABLE nj (ID INT)
CREATE TABLE nJ (ID INT)
CREATE TABLE Nj (ID INT)
CREATE TABLE NJ (ID INT)
```

In this case, when the first table is created, the 3rd and 4th will conflict but the second is allowed.

The SQL Engine looks to be taking any situation where the case of the letters is equivalent which is why lowercase `n` followed by uppercase `J` is considered a distinct name.